# Display an image if the accordion is open

Tags: javascript

I want to display an image if a pane of my accordion is open.

When one of the three shutters of the accordion opens, I want to show an image.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');
.question {
    color: #555;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #efefef;
}
.question:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.answer {
    color: #777;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

</style>
<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer" name"accordeon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<img id="myImgaa" src="" width="107" height="98">
<script>
$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function () {
    if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
    }
});
function myFunction() {
  const accordeon = document.querySelector('[name="accordeon"]');
  if ( $(this).next(".answer").is(":visible"))
  { 
    document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "https://cdn.wamiz.fr/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,quality=80,width=776,height=388,fit=cover/article/main-picture/chat-souris-main-5f4e10068679c.jpg";
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues with your current code.

There's an error in your HTML markup - `name"accordeon"` should be `name="accordeon"`. That's one of the reasons your code is not working.

The second issue is that you're not calling `myFunction` anywhere, you're just defining it.

And there's no real need to have a separate function like that (that I can see from your current code). A better thing to do would be to dismantle it, and use its parts in your click event handler, but the logic would be counterintuitive.

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function () {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $("#myImgaa").attr("src","");
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $("#myImgaa").attr("src","https://cdn.wamiz.fr/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,quality=80,width=776,height=388,fit=cover/article/main-picture/chat-souris-main-5f4e10068679c.jpg");
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');
.question {
    color: #555;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #efefef;
}
.question:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.answer {
    color: #777;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer" name="accordeon">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<img id="myImgaa" src="" width="107" height="98">
```

As you can see, I've placed the img source clearing in the `if is visible` part of your check, and the image showing in the `else` part of it (that's the counterintuitive part).

An additional change to your original code involves making everything use jQuery - while you can mix vanilla JS and jQuery, stick to using one of them.

As an aside - consider hiding the image instead of removing its source (unless there's a really good reason for removing it).

Comment: a very big thank you for your corrections and your explanations it works perfectly now

just a question is it possible to split the javascript into two parts

a part that takes care of folding and unfolding the accordion

the second part just to display or not to display the image

Comment: @pierre Sure, it's possible. Do you mean something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/petynasL/)? This was the easiest way of doing it. Another way of doing it would be to hook up into the sliding, and to do the actual hiding / src removing (or showing / src setting) once the sliding animation is complete. You could do that [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/petynasL/1/). The difference between the two is that the second one waits for the animation to finish before doing anything with the image, while the first one runs right away.

Comment: And yet another, more generic way of doing it is to have your function receive both the element and what it should do with it, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/petynasL/2/). By doing it like this, you can pass whatever you want, it doesn't have to be an image at all, since this solution is not doing anything with the source, just hiding or showing the received element. Of course, you can combine all of these into something which would work better for you, depending on what you need.

Comment: Once again a huge thank you, for the explanations, comments and corrections, this is super awesome
Have a good evening,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use this here:

```
function myFunction() {
    const accordeon = document.querySelector('[name="accordeon"]');
    if ( $(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")){ 
        document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "https://cdn.wamiz.fr/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,quality=80,width=776,height=388,fit=cover/article/main-picture/chat-souris-main-5f4e10068679c.jpg";
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "";
    }
}
```

Not sure when your function is called but try:

```
function myFunction() {
    const accordeon = document.querySelector('[name="accordeon"]');
    if ( $("#faq_slide .question").next(".answer").is(":visible")){ 
        document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "https://cdn.wamiz.fr/cdn-cgi/image/format=auto,quality=80,width=776,height=388,fit=cover/article/main-picture/chat-souris-main-5f4e10068679c.jpg";
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("myImgaa").src = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work
thank you for the answer

Comment: Are you calling the function? It works on my local install when I call myFunction()